# Unable to work with Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Initially I was working on Android in Eclipse and everything went fine. But two weeks before i installed Texlipse plugin and was working with it. Now, when i wanted to switch back to Android i'm unable to. 
In new project there's no option for creating a new Android project nor even a Java project.
Even i tried to change the Preference window to Java or Java Browsing but anything didn't work. Now i'm unable to run or compile even a single java file even after changing the perspective. I don't know whether this could be due to Texlipse, i tried searching google for ways to uninstall Texlipse but nothing worked.
So, pls anyone help me to sort this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unninstall eclipse and install ADT again

Comment: thanks:) Is there anything that can be done without uninstalling eclipse?  Because reinstalling eclipse was my last option..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play something before eclipse uninstall, what you can do is, go to your eclipse--->plugin folder (C:\eclipse\plugins something like this). There you will see all androind plugins which starts with com.android.....You may delete them and repeat the steps defined in this link.[Android eclipse setup](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

This is one try but can't guarantee (Remember this may messup your eclipse if it don't work, so get ready for eclipse unstall if it doesn't work).

Comment: thanks I tried this. But i made a fault by removing accidently one shared library required by eclipse and because of that eclipse wasn't starting at all and i had to reinstall eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

You could try launching Eclipse with the -clean parameter. This saved me when Eclipse was hanging on startup. Certainly worth a try before a re-install. More info here:

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html

Comment: thanks. tried with it but results were the same. But still the link was quite useful..

Answer (score 0):

- go to windows/android sdk manager. If it works and androids vesions you've choosed are there, AND you don't see android in eclipse, I am afraid you will need to reinstall everything.
- If sdk manager won't work, than install start sdk kit (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). After that run sdk manager and set up the packages you need. If it won't work,
- go to help/install new software and uninstall items that were installed in the backward sequence. After every remove check the prev step

I HAVE met the situations where only cleaning off all eclipse info and reinstalling it helped.

So, good luck!

Comment: thanks. But the problem i wasn't able to see Android SDK manager, even if the plugin was installed. But finally solved the problem by uninstalling Eclipse, removing all eclipse directories(i.e .eclipse in home directory) and reinstalling again.